# Mac Excel Date - Ruby encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having Mac Excel and trying to parse Date in ruby. Excel has a format like 12/10/11 .. and I am trying to get it as 12/10/11 in ruby. Right now when I parse the Excel using

```
@book = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse("..path")
sheet1 = @book.worksheet(1)
@number = sheet1.count
@abc = ""
sheet1.each do |cell|
    @hello = cell.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? true : false // if numeric
       if @hello == true
      // Trying to parse date into actual date without getting float...(Help needed)
     else     
        @abc += cell.join(',')+"*"
end
end
puts @abc
```

Can anyone please help me in this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `to_time` on it, and it will give you a DateTime object back which you can work with in Ruby.  Here is an example of how it could be done using the rails console:

```
> "12/10/11".to_time
=> Thu, 10 Dec 0011 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Do we need to use any require statements?

Comment: It is a function that is implemented in ActiveSupport, which is part of the rails core package, so you shouldn't need to use a require statement technically.  What version of rails are you using?  I was able to get it to work in `irb` by doing the following: https://gist.github.com/1534696

Comment: Docs for activesupport's `to_time` method: [here](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Conversions.html) and [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Conversions/to_time).

Comment: Rails 3.1.1
 and this is locked for my project . So I can't change that.

Comment: Just tried the same thing I did in the [gist I posted earlier](https://gist.github.com/1534696) using `ActiveSupport 3.1.1` and it also worked.  I would expect it to work in a typical rails file, but if it's not then try declaring `require 'active_support/all'`, as I showed in the gist.

Comment: It says..  nothing like that is defined.. Im stuck at that point.. Also I have a question .. Is there a way I can use javascript variable in HTML ERB tags?    
<%= Table.update_timesheet('query[i]')%>;
I am trying to get query[i] from javascript? is there a way? Can you please let me know?

Comment: Can you try running `rails console` and then trying to execute this command: `"12/10/11".to_time` and see what the response is?

Comment: The  version is fixed.. so i can't run that. I can only run script/server

Comment: If you run the app by doing script/server then you are likely running with Rails 2, not Rails 3.  Since Rails 3, you use `rails <command>` to execute commands.  What do you see if you run `rails --version`?

Comment: [Here are docs about using the rails command line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) for >= v3.0.

Comment: I am running Rails 3.1.1 but.. if i say rails console.. It is giving me kind of guide..

Comment: What OS are you using?  Is this a unix system?  Perhaps try running `script/console` instead of `rails console` if you have to run the server with `script/server`?  I'm kind of at a loss for how you could be running on Rails 3.1 but still using the `script/server` as the documentation clearly states that [you should be able to use a bunch of commands with the rails gem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#command-line-basics).  Did you not actually install the rails gem onto your system? One more important question: are you using bundler?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this.. I tried cell.date for each cell that im extracting from excel and that solved it... Thanks for your help..
Also I have a quick question.. I am trying to use a javascript varaiable in html erb. Like in <% %> tags..
query[i] is something I have in loop
I am trying to call
     <%= Table.update('query[i]')%>;
How can I have query[i] from javascript to be the actual value?

Comment: You need to ask start a fresh post for this new question - it probably won't get picked up here.